# f:ajax call is not working with f:validateRegex

Tags: ajax, validation, jsf-2

To my surprise, ajax call is **NOT** happening after each key that I enter in my text box. ajax is getting invoked **only after** 14 digits are entered. Not sure how ajax is related to validateRegex tag handler in this case? also, can I say `<f:validateRegex>, <f:valiadteLength>` etc will perform validations always at client side (like java script/jquery)?

```
<h:inputText id="input" value="#{bean.input}" maxlength="16">
<f:ajax event="keyup" render="another_id" listener="{bean.method}"/>
<f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]{14}" />
</h:inputText>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *ajax call is NOT happening after each key that I enter in my text box. ajax is getting invoked only after 14 digits are entered*

There's some confusion going on. The above statements are not true.

The ajax call is definitely invoked. Track the HTTP traffic in webbrowser's builtin developer toolset (press F12 in Chrome/IE9/Firebug and check the *Network* section). Create a HTTP filter on `/*` or a JSF `PhaseListener` and you'll see that it's been invoked on every key press (which means that the server is definitely hit every time).

You perhaps actually meant that the action listener method as specified in `<f:ajax listener>` is not been invoked. That is in turn indeed true. But that's fully expected behaviour. There's namely a validation error. This way JSF will **skip** the UPDATE_MODEL_VALUES and INVOKE_ACTION phases. So the action method is by design indeed not invoked. The business logic should namely not be performed when there's a validation error.

I'm not sure why you expected it to be invoked. Why would you execute business logic on invalid input? If you elaborate the concrete functional in more detail, then we may be able to propose the right approach for this.

---

**Update** as per the comments, just check the validity of the input component in the `disabled` attribute of the other components entirely in the view side by checking the outcome of [`UIInput#isValid()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#isValid%28%29) which you can get by binding the component to the view:

```
<h:inputText ... binding="#{input}">
    <f:ajax event="keyup" render="input2 input3 input4" />
    <f:validateRegex pattern="[0-9]{14}" />
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText id="input2" ... disabled="#{not input.valid}" />
<h:inputText id="input3" ... disabled="#{not input.valid}" />
<h:inputText id="input4" ... disabled="#{not input.valid}" />
```

No need for an ajax listener method.

Comment: hi balu... As Im not to answer my own question, here Im pasting my requirement in 3 different comments.

Comment: you are correct. I meant listener method is not getting invoked.

1) I hav 2 diff panel grids in my page
2) first panel grid has only one text box; 2nd one has 3 text boxes and a date picker
3) req 1 - is to disable all panel grid 2 specific components when the user start entering numbers in panel grid 1 text box.
4) req 2 - vice versa.

Comment: so, I've maintained 2 bean attributes say - attr1 and attr2 (one for panel grid1 componetns and another one for panel grid 2 components) by using which Im disabling the compoents. now the moment use enters a character in panel grid 1 text box, then ajax listener method will set 'attr2' to 'true' so that panel grid 2 compoentns will become refreshed and disabled. In the same way Im setting 'attr1' to 'true' when user starts entering charactrs in any of the panel grid2 specific components.

Comment: so in my case, client side validations (f:regEx or f:valdateLength etc) NEED NOT be performed immediately after each digit that user enters. but remember validation has to happen and with my own interest Im looking to use f:regEx client side validation instead of handling it at server side.
please suggest.

Comment: See answer update. Note that those are definitely not "client side validations".

Comment: thanks for ur comments. it should work. will give a try tomorrow and let you know the update.